# How can I connect an iOS / Android background service for GPS tracking to a Unity 5 based app

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, gps, location

I've already read a lot of questions and answers related to this topic, but I still have no clue how to start.

I developed a Unity 5 app for iOS and Android using the location service to find certain GPS areas or bluetooth (le) beacons. Everything runs fine, as long as the app is active and not paused in background. I know, that Unity is a game engine and that pausing apps is totally normal on mobile systems.
What I need, is a background service tracking the GPS position and/or beacon reception when the main app is hibernating. This service should at least play a sound, vibrate or even better, wake up the device and main app.

Is there a way to build that and to communicate between those two parts?

I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Have you tried Application.runInBackground = true; and then just switching to one scene that is running location services?